# how to write switch statement to identity Array Object in Crystal lang

Tags: switch-statement, crystal-lang

I want to transpose only 2d Array in Crystal lang, not 1d array.
So I write switch statement below.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[11,12,13]]
b = [1,2,3]

class Array
  def meow
    case self.first
    when Array
      puts self.transpose
    else
      puts "OK"
    end
  end
end

a.meow
b.meow
```

This code does not work. How can I fix it?
Here is the error message.

```
  Error in foo.cr:16: instantiating 'Array(Int32)#meow()'

  b.meow
    ^~~~

  in foo.cr:8: instantiating 'Array(Int32)#transpose()'

        puts self.transpose
                  ^~~~~~~~~

  in /usr/share/crystal/src/array.cr:1642: undefined method 'first' for Int32

      return Array(Array(typeof(first.first))).new if empty?
                                    ^~~~~
```

Comment: What is the real code for the OK part? What do you want meow to do when it's not a two dimensional array?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it is usually not recommended to monkey patch types from the standard library.

The problem can be solved relatively easy by assigning the array as an argument to the method and restricting the type to `Array(Array)`. Don't need to add specifics for any sub-types.

```
def meow(array : Array(Array))
  array.transpose
end

meow [[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 13]]    # => [[1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13]]
meow [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]] # => [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

You probably won't need a method accepting 1-dimensional arrays, so `meow [1, 2, 3]` will result in a compiler error.

It's possible to add an overload like this, though:

```
def meow(array : Array)
  "OK"
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One of solutions could be this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 13]]
b = [1, 2, 3]

class Array
  def meow
    case self
    when Array(Array(Int32))
      puts self.transpose
    else
      puts "OK"
    end
  end
end

a.meow
b.meow
```

Comment: Good answer! But what if other than Int32. Do I have to write all cases?

Comment: I don't know any other way, but maybe there is one.